# send data from php to android set

Tags: android

how to send data from php to android phone only knowing the receiver IMEI.I want to send a string that contain boolean value.Please help me out.is there any php command to do this.please help me out..

Answer (score 1):

You can send it trhough BlueTooth or SMS. And do some service to catch it internally.

Answer (score 0):

By only knowing the IMEI number, nobody can send any data to any device. You will need to have some kind of connection with the device to be able to send data directly.

Comment: the device is conneted to internet and i am also connected to internet.i know the persons cell number...Now is this possible.?

Comment: Nope. You need to look into some kind of Push notification for Android (c2dm etc) and implement it on the server side and the application side as well.

Comment: kindly tell me exactly wat to do

Comment: You will have to do a little bit of research and reading into this whole stuff. http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html